# set command output is 573 MB

Tags: bash, bashrc

I was making changes to `~/.bashrc` and resourcing it dozens of times with `. ~/.bashrc` this morning. The last time I noticed it was taking about 30 seconds to source the file.

So I did a quick test:

```bsh
$ time set | wc
   2925   16529 572654385

real    0m8.466s
user    0m7.855s
sys     0m1.166s
```

As you can see there is about 573 MB of `set` stuff. Dumping to screen I noticed most characters were `\`. So I counted the occurrence which is 395 million times:

```bsh
$ time fgrep -o '\' <<< $(set) | wc -l
395355002

real    0m57.086s
user    0m54.015s
sys     0m4.859s
```

Any clues on how to start narrowing down the cause in `~/.bashrc`?

It's 626 lines long and too long for someone to sift through. I have searched for `set -x` and `set +x` but those strings don't occur anywhere.

**NOTE:** When you open a new terminal `set` is much smaller:

```bsh
$ time set | wc
   2915    9330  114104

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.007s
```

Comment: sounds strange, I have 507 times `\`` ...

Comment: @pLumo When you source .bashrc does the set command output increase?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: me either. did many times.

Comment: @pLumo I found the solution. Thanks for taking time.

Comment: @DougSmythies I found the solution. Thanks for taking time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit. Output from `declare -p` was being saved to an array with the command:

```
mapfile -t SaveVars <<< "$(declare -p)"
```

Each time `~/.bashrc` was resourced the array was doubling in size, as was the contents of `declare -p`. Currently over `1.1 GB`:

```bsh
$ declare -p | wc
    123    8179 1,103,480,262
```

**NOTE:** Commas (`,`) added for readability.

Inserting one line to empty the array (and an appropriate comment line of course) results in this:

```bsh
# Empty array to prevent doubling everytime ~/.bashrc is resourced
SaveVars=()
# Save variable list before user creates new ones in shell
mapfile -t SaveVars <<< "$(declare -p)"
```

After this fix the size of variables stays the same after resourcing:

```bsh
$ declare -p | wc
    120    1008   30529

$ . ~/.bashrc

$ declare -p | wc
    120    1008   30529
```

Comment: :) ............

Comment: @bac0n It's a little hard to count but your comment implies a smile is worth a dozen dots: `fgrep -o '.' <<< ":) ............ – bac0n 1 hour ago" | wc -l` results in `12` :p